# Why am I getting AssertionError: Duplicate registrations for type 'experimentalOptimizer', keras version 2.13.1, tensorflow version 2.13.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

Code:

```
!pip install -U segmentation-models
import segmentation_models as sm
```

While importing segmentation_models I am getting the error

Error details:

> AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in <cell line: 1>()
> 1 import segmentation_models as sm
>
> 15 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/revived_types.py in register_revived_type(identifier, predicate, versions)
> 134
> 135   _REVIVED_TYPE_REGISTRY[identifier] = (predicate, versions)
> 136   _TYPE_IDENTIFIERS.append(identifier)
> 137
> 138
>
> AssertionError: Duplicate registrations for type 'experimentalOptimizer'